# Can anyone help me with this 2D custom array representation

Tags: data-structures

Assume that a 2D array of size “m x n” is stored contiguously in memory in the following way:

first row (or `0th` index row) is stored in row major.

Then the remaining elements   of   the   first   column   (or  `0th`  index  column)   are   stored   in   column   major.

Following this, the remaining elements of the second row (or 1th index row) is again stored in row major after which the remaining elements of second column (or  1thindex row) is stored in column major and so on.

Derive the expression to identify the address of an `(i, j)` th index element considering “base” to be the base address of the 2D array and indexing starts from “0”.

Comment: Can you please share an example?
For a 4 * 3 array like [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]], what will the output array look like?

Comment: @Md.FaisalHabib Of course an answer from the OP would be preferable, but my understanding would be [[1,2,3], [4,7,10], [5,6], [8,11], [9], [12]]

Comment: However, the formulation of the problem, in the imperative tense with no actual question, makes it sound like homework. I recommend reading this interesting [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)